# How can I write the below part of \bigcup like this?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,cases}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\displaystyle \mathcal{M}'= \bigcup_{ \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{E} ,\, \mathcal{F} \text{is countable}}\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}).$
\end{document}
```

Its output is:
[image]

But I want:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\substack{}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,cases}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\displaystyle \mathcal{M}'= \bigcup_{\substack{\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{E} \\ \mathcal{F} \text{ is countable}}}\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}).$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note `\substack` comes from amsmath, not mathtools. Is it made better with mathtools?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know that. I thought it was `mathtools`. Gonna edit

Comment: @DonaldArseneau -- `mathtools` loads `amsmath` and extends some of its facilities, mostly in response to legitimate requests from users.  (One example is matrices in which the horizontal alignment of the cells can be specified, rather than always being flush left, which looks dreadful when some entries are negative and others aren't.)  So if the extended facilities are needed, one can load `mathtools` and get both packages together.

Answer (score 2):

A spacing improvement with `\smashoperator` from `mathtools`  (neddless to load `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,cases}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
$\displaystyle \mathcal{M}'=\smashoperator{ \bigcup_{\substack{\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{E} \\ \mathcal{F} \text{ countable}}}}\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F}).$

\end{document}
```

[image]